# After deleting layers, in an animated GIF, how do I get rid of the GAP of nothing?

Tags: photoshop

Let me explain. Sergey answered my other question so I hope he catches this too.

I have 101 images. I deleted images 23 - 74.

When I run the animation, there's a GAP of NOTHING where those deleted layers were.

What happened and how do I fix it?

[image]

Anyone experience this before?

I tried renaming the layers above 24 to be in sequence, but that didn't help.

Thank you

UPDATE:

Here's the Save for the Web dialog with 101 layers still showing...

[image: Save for the Web Dialog]

Comment: Yes, when I deleted the unwanted layers, 24 - 73, I physically used the trashcan icon. They are GONE. My problem is, when the animation runs, where those layers used to be, there's nothing.  I used to have 101 layers and now I have 50. But the Save for the Web dialog still shows 101. See above under UPDATE: Thanks

Answer (score 5):

After searching I found the answer:

In Adobe Photoshop CC you simply goto Window ->> Timeline and POOF!!!

The timeline shows up below. Delete the frames you want, and wala! You're golden.

Comment: "Wala!" I love it! but it's actually "voila!". It's french. However I love "wala" so much that I'm going to start using it. Wala! You're golden!